# Change Dialogflow chatbot language in Facebook Messenger

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot

How to test the multilingual chatbot integrated to Facebook messenger, Dialogflow always uses English(Default language) when integrated to FB messenger.

I tried to changed the facebook profile settings also, but still it is not recognizing the other languages other than the English.

So, **How to test/work with multilingual chatbot in Facebook messenger?**

Thanks in Advance.

~ Praz Solver

Answer (score 0):

I´m actually after the same thing, I reached DialogFlow support, and they told me this:

> Thanks for reaching out to Dialogflow Support.
>
> At the moment, Dialogflow does not yet support multiple languages for any of its built-in integrations - so requests from Facebook Messenger will automatically only be sent to the Default Language of the agent.
>
> However, you can try to make your own implementation for this. You may consider creating a middleware that would serve as a bridge between your Dialogflow agent and your Facebook Messenger bot.
>
> When a user sends a query from Facebook Messenger, your middleware should detect which language was used and then it should send a detectIntent request (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent ) to Dialogflow containing both the query and a "languageCode" parameter field with the language tag (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/language ) of the end-user's language.
> You can use Dialogflow's REST API (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview ) or client libraries (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/libraries/overview ) to integrate your middleware to Dialogflow.
>
> More information about Multilingual Agents can be found at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-multilingual .